# There is a polynomial p(x) of degree two or less such that p(0)=0, p(1)=1, p'(b)=2. Find unique point x0 where p(x) is not satisfied.

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

There is a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree two or less such that

$$p(0)=0, p(1)=1, p'(b)=2$$

$b$ can be any value between $[0,1]$ except one point lets call that $x_0$.

Find $x_0$ and find the polynomial for $b\ne x_0$

The solution gives me $x_0 = \frac{1}{2}$.

My first step is to let the polynomial be $f(x)$. Since, the polynomial, is of degree $2$ or less. Let it be $px^2 + qx + r = 0$.

Since, $f(0) = 0 \implies 0 + 0 + r = 0 \implies r=0$.

Then the next step should be $p(1)=1$ which leads to $p+q+r=0 \implies p=-q$ since $r=0$. What do I do next? Thanks.

Comment: Do $p'(b)=2pb+q=2$ and look at the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\2b&1\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if $f(x)=px^2+qx+r$, then the conditions $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ imply $r=0$ and $q=1-p$, respectively.

Now we can reduce $f$ to the following form: $f(x)=px^2+(1-p)x$. Then $f'(x)=2px+(1-p)$, so the condition $f'(b)=2$ implies $$2pb+(1-p)=2\implies p(2b-1)=1\implies p=\frac{1}{2b-1}$$
So do you see what value of $b$ makes $p$ undefined?

Edit: the condition $f(1)=1$ actually implies $p+q=1\iff q=1-p$ (thanks to user296602 for pointing out the mistake). However, the value of $b$ which makes $p$ undefined is still the same, but the resulting polynomial will be different. My solution above is now correct.

Comment: pardon me but how did you get 2px−p=p(2x−1)?

Comment: @jamesblack just factor out the $p$. Both $2px$ and $p$ have a common factor of $p$, so $$2px-p=p(2x)-p=p(2x-1)$$

Comment: OH my bad for the stupid question; i thought p(2x-1) meant p as a transformed function

Comment: No worries. I will say that to avoid ambiguity in your solution, you should maybe not use $p$ as a coefficient of the polynomial, since the question sets $p(x)$ to be the polynomial.

Comment: $f(1) = 1$ actually implies that $p + q = 1$, not zero; this is a mistake the asker made.

Comment: @user296602 yes you're right, my mistake. Will edit.